# Turn all bulbs ON with a window of 3 bulbs

Tags: algorithm, math

I am working on building up my problem-solving approach and came across this problem.

We have N bulbs, randomly turned OFF, and ON. The objective is to turn them ON in minimum toggle iterations. 
We have to choose a set of 3 **consecutive** buttons at a time to toggle them.

Example(1-Bulb ON, 2-Bulb OFF):

00010110 can be turned all ON as

**000**10110 -> **111**10110

1111**011**0 --> 111**100**0

1111**000** --> 1111**111**

OR mention if It is not possible to turn them all ON.

I can't seem to get started with it.
Can someone please help me share an intuition on how to go about this?

Just need some inputs to get started, Not a complete solution.
Is this a specific category of problem? What is that category called?
I am open to reading material et all.

EDIT:

Can we have some optimization if we genralize the question for **K** consecutive buttons?

Comment: Yeah, They need to be consecutive.Yes, I am familiar with BFS.

Comment: The fact that you're asking for the category of problems suggests you're thinking about solving problems in the wrong way -- pattern matching them against existing problems rather than attacking them using a thinking/exploratory/experimental approach. Perhaps reading Polya's "how to solve it" would be valuable.

Comment: @PaulHankin: Thanks for referral. Ordered my copy :)

Answer (score 4):

Let's number the bulbs from left to right, as #1 through #*n*.

Some initial observations:

- It only matters which triples you toggle, not what order you toggle them in.
- There's never any point in toggling a given triple more than once: toggling it twice is equivalent to not having toggled it even once. Due to the previous point, this is true no matter what other togglings happen in between.
- There's only one triple that includes bulb #1: namely, the triple consisting of bulbs #1-3. Therefore, if bulb #1 is initially OFF, then you know you have to toggle that triple.
- For any given bulb #*i* in the range [2, *n*-2], there's only one triple that contains that bulb without containing the bulb to its left.

So:

- Go through each bulb #*i* in order from #1 to #*n*.

  - If the bulb is currently OFF:

    - If *i* is less than or equal to *n*-2:

      - Toggle bulbs #*i* to #*i*+2.
    - Otherwise:

      - Return "sorry, can't be solved!".

Comment: Does this approach guarantees minimum no. of toggles? If yes, how?

Comment: can you please help share inputs?

Comment: Yes it will give the minimum number of toggles because you only toggle if you have to.